# Why is 'apt-cache search' and 'find / -name' showing files associated with a package i have already purged?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, libreoffice, purge, apt-cache

I specifically installed libreoffice-writer on my system and then purged it with `sudo apt-get purge '*libreoffice-writer*' --autoremove`. After this i ran these terminal commands one after the other to ascertain whether i actually got rid of all the files associated with libreoffice or libreoffice-writer -

```
apt-cache search libreoffice-writer

sudo find / -name libreoffice
```

[image: command output image]

and then i ran `apt-cache search libreoffice` and it displayed dozens of files with the name 'libreoffice'
[image: output image]

As you can see in the terminal images, why are there so many associated files still left? How do i get rid of all of these files in such a way that the next time i install anything from libreoffice it should install itself like it was installing for the first time on my system ?

Comment: `apt-cache search` searches files found in your software lists (ie. from data from `apt update` and doesn't limit itself to installed packages - allowing you to find what you can install etc).   I'm not using Kubuntu & don't have `kubuntu-desktop` installed; but I can `apt-cache search kubuntu-desktop` to confirm that package contains what I think it is... ie. it's searching my software lists cache... not installed packages.

Comment: I said "`apt-cache search` searches files found" in my prior comment; that should be **packages** not files sorry.

Comment: You mean the 'purge' command doesn't get rid of files in the cache? Are these files in cache temporary then? waiting to be disappeared after i reboot/re-login? This is Ubuntu 21.10 btw.

Comment: The package list is updated by the execution of the `apt update` command.  You don't install packages with that command, but when you subsequently use `apt install`... `apt-cache` reads from the cache downloaded by the prior `apt update` command & includes all packages available to your system by sources you have enabled/added (be they installed, or not installed).   I'm assuming you're not using Kubuntu & thus don't have it installed - use the example I used in prior comment.. `apt-cache` is used to search for packages available to you..

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Ironically, posting pictures of words sort of creates an issue the same as the one you are having. When someone searches`libreoffice-sdbc-firebird`, for example, they expect to see all Qs associated with the term, however this one will not show up. Even though it is right there. In your situation, even though the files say `libreoffice`, they are not associated with that package. At least in many of the cases.

Comment: `How do i get rid of all of these files` - this should work: `find / -iname "*libreoffice*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rfv`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apt maintains a local database of all available deb package from all currently-known sources. "Available" means that **it includes packages that you don't currently have installed** as well as the packages that you DO currently have installed.

- `apt-cache` searches the database
- `apt update` refreshes the database from those sources
- `apt list libreoffice-writer` or `apt list libreoffice*` will specify which packages in the output are installed.

---

Now let's look at files and directories that remain after a --purge.

- Directories may remain if they are not empty after apt is done removing files. Some other package (or the admin) may be using the directory, too.
- Apt will NEVER remove any file located under your /home directory. (The manpage is very clear about that)

---

A word about using wildcards with apt: Many users are surprised when wildcards cause extra packages to be marked for action, and when packages they expected to be marked aren't.

There could be lots of possible reasons why you get an action different than you expect: Dependencies, unexpected names, misspellings, wrong wildcard, etc.

There are two schools of thought on safe, effective usage of wildcards with apt:

1. Use apt's `--simulate` to test the action first. Review your output and find the unexpected BEFORE doing it for real.
2. Avoid using wildcards at all. Use apt's tools to KNOW the correct packages you want to act upon. Then list those packages.

Comment: It all makes sense now. On your suggestion to list all the installed packages, i ran the command( 'apt-cache search libreoffice-writer --installed' ) but the terminal says '--installed' is not understood in combination with other options. Don't you think 'apt-cache search' is a poor choice to search for installed packages here?

Comment: Thanks for noticing the error. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

`apt-cache search` searches packages found in your software lists (ie. from data from `apt update` and doesn't limit itself to installed packages - allowing you to find what you can install etc).

I'm not using Kubuntu & don't have `kubuntu-desktop` installed; but I can `apt-cache search kubuntu-desktop` to confirm that package contains what I think it is; it's available for my system, I've remembered the name correctly etc & can then decide to install it.  ie. it's searching my *software lists cache*... not my installed packages.

The package list is updated by the execution of the `apt update` command. You don't install packages with that command, but when you subsequently use `apt install`... `apt-cache` reads from the *cache* downloaded by the prior `apt update` command & includes all packages available to your system by sources you have enabled/added (*be they installed, or not installed*).

Comment: prior comments *massaged gently* into rough answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `dpkg --list | grep -i libreoffice` to determine LibreOffice related installed packages.

If LibreOffice related files were installed using APT then they should be removed this way. To automate the process use below command:

```
sudo apt-get autopurge $(dpkg --list | grep -i libreoffice | awk '{print $2}')
```

**and do not remove files controlled by APT manually**.

---

Stuff to read:

1. [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)
2. [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt.8.html)
3. [`man apt-cache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html)